# Initializing boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> with boost::shared_ptr<std::list<T>>

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to initialize a `boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string> > vec` in the constructor initialize list with an `boost::shared_ptr<std::list<std::string> > list`?

Is it possible?

I tried this:

Test.hpp

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(boost::shared_ptr<std::list<std::string> > list);

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string> > vec;
};
```

Test.cpp

```
Test::Test(boost::shared_ptr<std::list<std::string> > list) : vec(list->begin(), list->end())
{
}
```

Part of error message:

```
Test.cpp: In constructor ‘Test::Test(boost::shared_ptr<std::list<std::basic_string<char> > >)’:
Test.cpp:6:85: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::shared_ptr(std::list<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::list<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator)’
```

Comment: Of course not. These are different types. You have to create the vector and copy the list contents to it.

Comment: Although there are valid cases for shared pointers to containers, are you sure you need shared lifetime and dynamic allocation ef containers here?

Comment: Just a remark: `boost::shared_ptr` is history. Use C++11 standard features instead: `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I need to use `boost::shared_ptr`, I don't have access to C++11 features...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace:

```
vec(list->begin(), list->end())
```

with:

```
vec(boost::make_shared(list->begin(), list->end()))
```

Your constructor should looks like:

```
Test::Test(const boost::shared_ptr<std::list<std::string> >& list) :
    vec(boost::make_shared(list->begin(), list->end())){
}
```

Be aware that you are copying the data from the `std::list` to the `std::vector`.

If you want less expensive solution, you could move them using  `std::make_move_iterator`. However, since you still using boost smart pointers, I think that you do not have access to it.

**Edit:**

if it did not work try this:

```
vec(boost::make_shared<std::vector<std::string>>(list->begin(), list->end()))
```

**Edit 2:**

In order to cover the `nullptr` case as it was mentioned by @Maxim Egorushkin:

```
class Test{
public:
    Test(const boost::shared_ptr<std::list<std::string> >& list);

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string> > convert_to_vec(const boost::shared_ptr<std::list<std::string> >& lst) const;
    boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string> > vec;
};

//in .cpp
Test::Test(const boost::shared_ptr<std::list<std::string> >& list):
    vec(convert_to_vec(list)){
}
boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string> > Test::convert_to_vec(const boost::shared_ptr<std::list<std::string> >& lst) const{
    if(lst!=nullptr){
        return boost::make_shared<std::vector<std::string>>(list->begin(), list->end());
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that the constructor should just take a `const std::list<std::string>&`, as it shouldn't need to know about the lifetime of the list. I understand just answering the question though :)

Comment: I got this error message:
`Test.cpp: In constructor ‘Test::Test(const boost::shared_ptr<std::list<std::basic_string<char> > >&)’:
Test.cpp:6:123: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_shared(std::list<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::list<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator)’`

Comment: @tmsblgh Try `boost::make_shared<std::list<std::string>>(list->begin(), list->end())`.

Comment: @TartanLlama `Test.cpp: In constructor ‘Test::Test(const boost::shared_ptr<std::list<std::basic_string<char> > >&)’:
Test.cpp:6:149: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::shared_ptr(boost::detail::sp_if_not_array<std::list<std::basic_string<char> > >::type)’`

Comment: `boost::shared_ptr<>` can be `nullptr`.

Comment: Looks too complicated for the code that does not do anything useful. It is `shared_ptr`s fault, not yours.

Answer (score 3):

As a side note: it is not clear why the constructor takes `shared_ptr<X>` but does not use the `shared_ptr<X>`. It should take `X&` instead. Avoid using smart-pointers if possible.

Ideally, your code should look like:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(std::list<std::string> const& list)
        : vec(list.begin(), list.end())
    {}

private:
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
};
```

Comment: Am I need to pass only std::list<std::string>& list? Using shared_ptr is not "safer" & "cheaper"?

Comment: Yes, pass `std::list<std::string> const& list` if possible, avoid passing around `shared_ptr`s. And avoid having `shared_ptr` members if possible.